How to Calculate the Rectified Voltage in a 220V AC Detection Circuit?
I am looking for a 220V AC detection circuit and saw an article with the following circuit:  
Reference article: https://www.instructables.com/AC-Mains-Detector-Circuit/
How can I approximately calculate the rectified voltage on the D1 bridge with R1 = 150k, using the datasheet or any relevant equation?

Peak mains voltages will be \$\pm(220\rm{V_{RMS}} \times \sqrt2)=\pm 310V\$. Due to the diode bridge, the output always has the same polarity, so the equivalent circuit during peaks in either half cycle is the same (ignoring diodes that are not conducting, and disregarding the order of R1 and V1):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The peak voltage between the DC outputs (+ and −) of the diode bridge is the sum of the forward voltages of LED1 and the opto-isolator LED. If LED1 is red, this will be a little over 3V total.
In fact this will be the voltage during much of every half-cycle, since the diode voltages remain roughly constant regardless of current.
Zener diode D2 plays no role. It would have been necessary if the diode bridge were absent, to limit LED reverse bias voltage. It looks like the author inserted the diode bridge and didn't notice that D2 was no longer necessary.
Edit: @kaosad raised a good point in the comments. If LED1 or the opto LED opens, then C1 would charge beyond its voltage rating. D2 does indeed protect C1 from destruction.

Yes, the D2 Zener diode plays no role when everything is fine. However, if the opto or LED1 is faulty, causing the circuit to be open, it will raise the voltage of the capacitor (most likely a low-voltage type) to the mains peak voltage, potentially causing an explosion. D2 is there for safety purposes.

@kaosad Fair point
